# React web-page won't display on server

Tags: reactjs, npm, server, react-router

I have been trying to deploy my `create-react-app` on a server but have been unable to do so. I created a homepage field in the `package.json` as instructed and set it to the `https://...` domain address. Then I ran `npm run build` and created the build file. I am finding resources sparse online, instructing me what to do after. Running `npm start` just runs from the root directory, not displaying anything. The source shows and `index.html` file which paths are stuck at the root. I am wondering what I need to do to run/deploy the build(production). I have tried downloading the npm package serve, but this seems to do the same as npm run, if not worse. I feel like I am only moving in the opposite direction, and would love some assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Basically, you need a web server like Apache, Nginx or IIS.

Comment: My linux-support team gave me a URL and he said to just start it there. Isn't that something along the lines of an apache server?

Comment: Should I ask him what server he is using and find the command to run my build folder using that server brand/type?

Comment: That's really a question that you need to clarify with your IT department. We don't know about your IT architecture

Comment: After building, you basically need to have a webserver like already said which would then host the static files from the `build` folder (default). Does this help you?

Comment: @NoHoney_k1ll good point.

Comment: @YoungScooter I deployed many apps with Now sh using just create-react-app!

Comment: @rsz Should I have just the build folder in the server? Not the entire project?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yes, I really should clarify with them.

Comment: @NoHoney_k1ll: No, that's a very bad point. It uses node to perform its work and it contains a development web server but it *does not* contain a production ready web server.

Comment: @NoHoney_k1ll I thought you just said why would I need another web server. Isn't that what Now does? I was just looking at their docs and I needed a bunch of docker stuff and so forth.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `npm build`.
This creates files in the `build` folder.
These files you then need to take and put them in a folder that is served by a web server.
You can use Nginx, Apache, IIS or any other *production ready* web server.
You have an IT department, ask them where exactly you need to put your files.

Comment: At any point am I typing `npm start` or do I literally just put the static files (the build folder) in the place where I need to. And if the server is running, it should do its job.

Comment: That's right, you do NOT type npm start for your production server. Copy the files to the server directory and done (assuming the server is running)

Comment: Thank you. I will get back to you on this, but I will talk to IT and do as you put it. Seems simple enough.

Comment: When I asked him if I should set up and Apache web server instance or if he had already done so, he said this: 

"Apache is just proxying to your application on port 3000. Any web content that needs to be served via your application can be served directly from your application without an interim web server."

Not exactly sure what he means by this.

Comment: It means that he expects you to use npm start. Please tell him that this is not a good idea because this is not a production ready web server.

Comment: We got it working. Thank you very much @DanielHilgarth. I was so very close. Had to use 'serve' on the Apache server at port 3000 instead of 5000.